# Laravel Nova – Manually Send Error Alert From Observer Class

Tags: laravel, observers, laravel-nova

I have a Season Resource model with a field named `active.`

The requirement is to disable deletion for a `season` with an active status.

I have created an Observer for the season model to watch deleting an event. From this function, I can block the delete in case `active` is true.

But the issue is with the error message; is there any way to add an error message to session flash from the Observer class?

```php
<?php

public function deleting(Season $season)
{
    if($season->active_season)
    {
        Log::info('Sorry, this season can`t be deleted. 
            There must be at least one active season.');
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to flash the error message.

But since the requirement is to disable deletion for a season with an active status, I'm suggesting to use [policy](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/authorization.html#policies) which won't display the delete icon when doesn't match the condition.

```
class SeasonPolicy {
    ...

    public function delete(User $user, Season $season) {
        if($season->active_season) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

and register the policy in `AuthServiceProvider`.

**Note:**

> Undefined Policy Methods
>
> If a policy exists but is missing a method for a particular action,
>   the user will not be allowed to perform that action. So, if you have
>   defined a policy, don't forget to define all of its relevant
>   authorization methods.

Answer (score 2):

This is not tested but I was able to achieve something like that in a previous project:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class AbcObserver
{
    public function creating(Abc $abc)
    {
        if ($abc->details != 'test') {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages(['details' => 'This is not valid.']);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Exception` class. I tested it in a Nova action and it throws the toast error notification.

```php
use Exception;

throw new Exception('Error message here ...');

// Or

throw_if(
    $validator->fails(), // or any true boolean
    Exception::class,
    'Error message here ...'
);
```

Comment: When it used on production environment then it gives a server error.

Comment: @MuhammadSulman What's the error? Show me your code.

Comment: Anyway, I did it solved, by using the custom exception class, because, default exception return 500  error code, I just override it and used any other code of 500 series, and then it displayed my custom error message.

Otherwise, it did not display my custom error message, only displayed "server error" which is not acceptable for layman users.